# Matplotlib B1-Motion (mouse motion with key held down) equivalent?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

Is there a matplotlib event that is similar the the Tkinter `<B1-Motion>` key? Such that a function is called only when the user is holding B1 down while moving the mouse?

I'm current looking into [this](http://matplotlib.org/api/backend_bases_api.html) documentation but don't see such an option, if not is there some simple way I can recreate this?

```
def notify_motion(event):
    """
    Only called when button 1 is clicked and motion detected
    """

    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`canvas.mpl_connect`](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) doesn't provide a key_down+motion event. A possible hack is to store a property of whether the mouse button (or key) is hold down and use the `motion_notify_event`.

In this example, tho in `wx`, we can hold mouse down and draw a red rectangle over a plot:

```
import wx
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.boxSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(orient=wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(self.boxSizer1)
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.boxSizer1.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.x0 = None
        self.y0 = None
        self.x1 = None
        self.y1 = None
        self.axes   = [self.figure.add_subplot(111), ]
        self.axes[0].plot(range(100), range(100))
        self.canvas.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.ChangeCursor)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_press)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.on_release)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.on_motion)
        self.rect = Rectangle((0,0), 1, 1, fill=False, ec='r')
        self.axes[0].add_patch(self.rect)
        #store a property of whether the mouse key is pressed
        self.pressed = False



    def ChangeCursor(self, event):
        '''Change cursor into crosshair type when enter the plot area'''
        self.canvas.SetCursor(wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_CROSS))



    def on_press(self, event):
        '''Draw ROI rectangle'''
        self.pressed = True
        self.x0 = int(event.xdata)
        self.y0 = int(event.ydata)


    def on_release(self, event):
        '''When mouse is on plot and button is released, redraw ROI rectangle, update ROI values'''
        self.pressed = False
        self.redraw_rect(event)


    def redraw_rect(self, event):
        '''Draw the ROI rectangle overlay'''
        try:
            self.x1 = int(event.xdata)
            self.y1 = int(event.ydata)
            self.rect.set_xy((self.x0, self.y0))
            self.rect.set_width(self.x1 - self.x0)
            self.rect.set_height(self.y1 - self.y0)
        except:
            pass
        self.canvas.draw()

    def on_motion(self, event):
        '''If the mouse is on plot and if the mouse button is pressed, redraw ROI rectangle'''
        if self.pressed:
            # redraw the rect
            self.redraw_rect(event)

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = Frame(None)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        frame.Show(True)
        return True

if __name__=='__main__':
    app=App(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I have not idea whether you are still care about this issue, anyway there is a very simple solution using the `button` attribute of [`matplotlib.backend_bases.MouseEvent`](https://matplotlib.org/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.MouseEvent) class, since `event.button` will be `1` if the cursor is being pressed and `None` if it is being released.

Following is my code to draw a line by holding and moving the cursor:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def moved_and_pressed(event):
    if event.button==1:
        x = np.append(line.get_xdata(), event.xdata)
        y = np.append(line.get_ydata(), event.ydata)
        line.set_data(x, y)
        fig.canvas.draw()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(5,3), dpi=100)
line, = ax.plot([], [], 'k')
ax.set_xlim(0,10); ax.set_ylim(0,10)
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', moved_and_pressed)
plt.show()
```

Hope it helps.