# Combining matplotlib's mouse button events with pick events

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget, scatter-plot

Based on combination of mouse button and key events, different functionalities are applied to the points of a scatter plot. When the left mouse button is pressed matplotlib's [Lasso](http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/lasso_demo.html) widget is called and with the included points functionality 1 takes place. When `Shift+LMB` are pressed a `Lasso` is drawn and functionality 2 takes place with the included points. When `Alt+LMB` are pressed a `Lasso` is drawn and with the included points functionality 3 takes place. Last, but not least, when I press the `RMB` a pick event is triggered and the index of the selected point in the scatter plot is given.

Since I added the `pick` event, the aforementioned functionalities work correctly until a `pick` event is triggered for the **first time**. When it is triggered it seems that the canvas gets locked and I can not use any other functionality. Although, I get the index of the selected point, I do not get any errors, and the canvas becomes unresponsive.

I modified the code taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32322090/combine-key-and-mouse-button-events-in-wxpython-panel-using-matplotlib) question, which is actually what I want to do.

**Code:**

```
import logging
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.widgets import Lasso
from matplotlib.colors import colorConverter
from matplotlib.collections import RegularPolyCollection
from matplotlib import path
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import rand

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


class Datum(object):
      colorin = colorConverter.to_rgba('red')
      colorShift = colorConverter.to_rgba('cyan')
      colorCtrl = colorConverter.to_rgba('pink')
      colorout = colorConverter.to_rgba('blue')

      def __init__(self, x, y, include=False):
         self.x = x
         self.y = y
         if include:
            self.color = self.colorin
         else:
            self.color = self.colorout


class LassoManager(object):
      def __init__(self, ax, data):
         self.axes = ax
         self.canvas = ax.figure.canvas
         self.data = data

         self.Nxy = len(data)

         facecolors = [d.color for d in data]
         self.xys = [(d.x, d.y) for d in data]
         fig = ax.figure
         self.collection = RegularPolyCollection(fig.dpi, 6, sizes=(100,),facecolors=facecolors, offsets = self.xys, transOffset = ax.transData)

         ax.add_collection(self.collection)

         self.pick=self.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.onpick)
         self.cid = self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.onpress)
         self.keyPress = self.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.onKeyPress)
         self.keyRelease = self.canvas.mpl_connect('key_release_event', self.onKeyRelease)
         self.lasso = None
         self.shiftKey = False
         self.ctrlKey = False

      def callback(self, verts):
          logging.debug('in LassoManager.callback(). Shift: %s, Ctrl: %s' % (self.shiftKey, self.ctrlKey))
          facecolors = self.collection.get_facecolors()
          p = path.Path(verts)
          ind = p.contains_points(self.xys)
          for i in range(len(self.xys)):
              if ind[i]:
                 if self.shiftKey:
                    facecolors[i] = Datum.colorShift
                 elif self.ctrlKey:
                    facecolors[i] = Datum.colorCtrl
                 else:
                    facecolors[i] = Datum.colorin
                    print self.xys[i]
              else:
                   facecolors[i] = Datum.colorout

          self.canvas.draw_idle()
          self.canvas.widgetlock.release(self.lasso)
          del self.lasso

      def onpress(self, event):
           if self.canvas.widgetlock.locked(): return
           if event.inaxes is None:    return
           self.lasso = Lasso(event.inaxes, (event.xdata, event.ydata), self.callback)
           # acquire a lock on the widget drawing
           self.canvas.widgetlock(self.lasso)

      def onKeyPress(self, event):
          logging.debug('in LassoManager.onKeyPress(). Event received: %s (key: %s)' % (event, event.key))
          if event.key == 'alt':
             self.ctrlKey = True
          if event.key == 'shift':
             self.shiftKey = True

      def onKeyRelease(self, event):
          logging.debug('in LassoManager.onKeyRelease(). Event received: %s (key: %s)' % (event, event.key))
          if event.key == 'alt':
             self.ctrlKey = False
          if event.key == 'shift':
             self.shiftKey = False


      def onpick(self,event):

          if event.mouseevent.button == 3:

             index = event.ind
             print('onpick scatter:', index, np.take(x, index), np.take(y, index))

      if __name__ == '__main__':

         x,y =rand(2,100)
         data = [Datum(*xy) for xy in zip(x,y)]
         fig = plt.figure()
         ax = plt.axes()

         ax.scatter(x,y,picker=True)

         lman = LassoManager(ax, data)
         plt.show()
```

Any suggestions on what might be causing this malfunction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're having this time is that you have both a `PickEvent` and a `MouseEvent` that are generated at the same time when you click on an artist. The `MouseEvent` locks the canvas and prevents you from doing anything else afterward.

The best solution would be to prevent the `MouseEvent` from being fired after the `PickEvent`, but I don't know if there's a way to do that. Instead, I added a test to check whether `onpress()` was called after `onpick()` to disable the locking mechanism.

```
import logging
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.widgets import Lasso
from matplotlib.colors import colorConverter
from matplotlib.collections import RegularPolyCollection
from matplotlib import path
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import rand

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


class Datum(object):
      colorin = colorConverter.to_rgba('red')
      colorShift = colorConverter.to_rgba('cyan')
      colorCtrl = colorConverter.to_rgba('pink')
      colorout = colorConverter.to_rgba('blue')

      def __init__(self, x, y, include=False):
         self.x = x
         self.y = y
         if include:
            self.color = self.colorin
         else:
            self.color = self.colorout


class LassoManager(object):
      def __init__(self, ax, data):
         self.axes = ax
         self.canvas = ax.figure.canvas
         self.data = data

         self.Nxy = len(data)

         facecolors = [d.color for d in data]
         self.xys = [(d.x, d.y) for d in data]
         fig = ax.figure
         self.collection = RegularPolyCollection(fig.dpi, 6, sizes=(100,),facecolors=facecolors, offsets = self.xys, transOffset = ax.transData)

         ax.add_collection(self.collection)

         self.cid = self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.onpress)
         self.keyPress = self.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.onKeyPress)
         self.keyRelease = self.canvas.mpl_connect('key_release_event', self.onKeyRelease)
         self.pick=self.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.onpick)
         self.lasso = None
         self.shiftKey = False
         self.ctrlKey = False
         self.pickEvent = False

      def callback(self, verts):
          logging.debug('in LassoManager.callback(). Shift: %s, Ctrl: %s' % (self.shiftKey, self.ctrlKey))
          facecolors = self.collection.get_facecolors()
          p = path.Path(verts)
          ind = p.contains_points(self.xys)
          for i in range(len(self.xys)):
              if ind[i]:
                 if self.shiftKey:
                    facecolors[i] = Datum.colorShift
                 elif self.ctrlKey:
                    facecolors[i] = Datum.colorCtrl
                 else:
                    facecolors[i] = Datum.colorin
                    print self.xys[i]
              else:
                   facecolors[i] = Datum.colorout

          self.canvas.draw_idle()
          self.canvas.widgetlock.release(self.lasso)
          del self.lasso

      def onpress(self, event):
            logging.debug('in LassoManager.onpress(). Event received: %s' % event)
            if self.pickEvent:
                self.pickEvent = False
                return
            if self.canvas.widgetlock.locked(): return
            if event.inaxes is None: return
            self.lasso = Lasso(event.inaxes, (event.xdata, event.ydata), self.callback)
            # acquire a lock on the widget drawing
            self.canvas.widgetlock(self.lasso)

      def onKeyPress(self, event):
          logging.debug('in LassoManager.onKeyPress(). Event received: %s (key: %s)' % (event, event.key))
          if event.key == 'alt':
             self.ctrlKey = True
          if event.key == 'shift':
             self.shiftKey = True

      def onKeyRelease(self, event):
          logging.debug('in LassoManager.onKeyRelease(). Event received: %s (key: %s)' % (event, event.key))
          if event.key == 'alt':
             self.ctrlKey = False
          if event.key == 'shift':
             self.shiftKey = False

      def onpick(self, event):
          logging.debug('in LassoManager.onpick(). Event received: %s' % event)
          self.pickEvent = True
          if event.mouseevent.button == 3:
             index = event.ind
             print 'onpick scatter: ', index, np.take(x, index), np.take(y, index)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x,y =rand(2,100)
    data = [Datum(*xy) for xy in zip(x,y)]
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes()

    ax.scatter(x,y,picker=True)

    lman = LassoManager(ax, data)
    plt.show()
```